# Output prints **None** and i have no idea how it came & need help to get rid of it

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

When i am printing value from a variable who derives value from a function within a class, It prints **None**. Need to know why and how can we get ignore this

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I have uploaded image that can be accessed when u click my question "**When i am printing value from a variable who derives value from a function within a class, It prints None. Need to know why and how can we get ignore this**"

Comment: class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self.radius=radius

    def area(self):
        print (3.14*self.radius*self.radius)
    def perimeter(self):
        print (2*3.14*self.radius)

circle = Circle(3)

circle_area = circle.area()
circle_perimeter = circle.perimeter()

print (circle_area)
print (circle_perimeter)

Comment: @Nizar , i have pasted code in comments

Comment: Please edit the question to contain all code, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: you need to return a value on your defs, not just print it. No return value => gets none as the return!

Comment: Please type the code in the provided textbox, while asking a question. Please dont attach images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in the methods `area` and `perimeter`, you are `printing` the result instead of `returning` it.

When you want to store the value of a method in a variable, you have to `return` that value.

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return (3.14 * self.radius * self.radius)

    def perimeter(self):
        return (2 * 3.14 * self.radius)

circle = Circle(3)

circle_area = circle.area()
circle_perimeter = circle.perimeter()

print(circle_area)
print(circle_perimeter)
```